# Cannot update from Gatsby 2.12.78 to 3.X globally

Tags: node.js, npm, package, gatsby, updates

I have tried running `npm i -g gatsby-cli` and `sudo npm i -g gatsby-cli` but when I run `gatsby --version` it still says 2.12.78 even though it also says "Update available 2.12.78 → 3.10.0 | Run npm i -g gatsby-cli to update"

These are my package versions:

npm version: 7.19.1

node version: v16.5.0

Gatsby CLI version: 2.12.78

Answer (score 0):

You just need to follow the [migration guide](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/migrating-from-v2-to-v3/):

```
npm install gatsby@latest
```

All `gatsby-*` should be upgraded too, but without updating the global Gatsby package you can't update the related ones. Check them by:

```
npm outdated
```